# How to iterate over Django model fields, and add values based on a condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that simulates a train line with up to 30 stations, so the model has 30 nullable fields.

**models.py**

```py
class TempLine(models.Model):
    picking_mode = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    start_station = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    end_station = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_1 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_2 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_3 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_4 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_5 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_6 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_7 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_8 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_9 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_10 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_11 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_12 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_13 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_14 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_15 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_16 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_17 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_18 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_19 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_21 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_22 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_23 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_24 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_25 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_26 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_27 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_28 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_29 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    station_30 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
```

The data is being added one by one using ajax request.

so I have to loop through all the fields starting from `station_1` ..checking if it is none, add .. if not .. just go for next one.

here is how I tried to do it:

```py
def adding_inline_stations(request):
    in_line_station = request.GET.get('inLine_stations', None)
    obj = TempLine.objects.filter()[0]
    for f in obj._meta.get_fields[3:]:
        if f is None:
            f = in_line_station
            f.save()
        else:
            pass
```

that returns an error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a station model. Whilst at the minute you only need the name of the station, it could quite quickly grow into needing a location, opening times etc..

Once you've made such a model (even if it just has a single field at the minute with a name), make a many to many relationship with your line and access them in the same way as any other related model field.

As a general programming rule, if you're naming variables `variable_n`, then its time to rethink if you need to store these objects in a collection of some sort

Answer (score 1):

First the error: `<Model>._meta.get_fields` is a method, not an attribute; so you need:

```
for f in obj._meta.get_fields()[3:]:
# Note the call:             ^^
```

Now, your design does not seem right. What you're doing is basically a call for a relation with a `Station` model. So, create a `Station` model with e.g. a `name` field containing the name of the station (and other fields as needed). Also make sure you think about the relationship to use with the `Line` model clearly; at first look, it looks like a many-to-many to me.